# Code in viewDidAppear is not executed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner Swift user who wants to open a popup as soon as my app starts. To this end I use the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func viewDidAppear(){
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
      "PasswordPopUp") as? PasswordPopUp {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("error creating PasswordPopUp")
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as if the code in viewDidAppear is not executed at all. This is probably dumb but what have I done wrong? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: This is a good example where you should let Xcode complete code for you. It helps ensure you get the correct method signature.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`. By saying:

```
func viewDidAppear() {
}
```

You are declaring a new method, other than `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`.

You should use:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // The rest of your code.
}
```

Just type `viewDidA` and Xcode will auto-complete it for you.

Comment: And it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to know that, You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Correct method

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool){ 

  super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"PasswordPopUp") as? PasswordPopUp {
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
      present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
    print("error creating PasswordPopUp")
   }


}
```